# coqsoft formatting cell value to be 0.00 in case it is 0

Tags: c#, treegrid

I have a page that is using the coqsoft grid, and the cells of type int are displayed either with a value or empty if the value is zero, I don't want that, I want the grid to display either a value or 0.00 if the value is zero.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I didn't try, This is a configuration to the grid, I tried searching the documentation on treegrid.com, but it is not clear and I couldn't find, how can I format Cells for the zero value case, I already know the negative and positive formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the column XML use this:

```
Format="0.00;-0.00;0.00"
```

The first value is the format of the number in case it is positive, the second in case it is negative, the 3rd in case it is zero. Also you can use `",0.00"` if you want a thousands separator.

You can also add this format in the definition XML or in data rows with column name appended like this `"Col1Format"`